# Send JSON array from Javascript and receive values in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send JSON array from Javascript to Php to be inserted into the database. I can see the array being display on the console log but what I do not know is how to receive it in Php. The JSON array will be used in my cascading option list where the chosen values are going to be displayed in a table. That is where the function SaveData will get the value to be sent in Php.

```js
var ModelArray = {
  "Mammals": {
    "Dog": {
      "Dog Food": ["Milk"]
    },
    "Cat": {
      "Cat food": ["Milk"]
    },
    "Tiger": {
      "Meat": ["Water"]
    },
    "Monkey": {
      "Banana": ["Water"]
    }
  },
  "Reptiles": {
    "Snake": {
      "Rat": ["None"]
    },
    "Turtle": {
      "Plant": ["Water"]
    },
    "Lizard": {
      "Insects": ["None"]
    },
    "Crocodile": {
      "Meat": ["Water"]
    }
  }
}


function SaveData() {

  var DataList = [];
  var table = document.getElementById("bod");
  var rowLength = table.rows.length;

  //loops through rows    
  for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {

    //gets cells of current row  
    var oCells = table.rows.item(i).cells;

    //gets amount of cells of current row
    //var cellLength = oCells.length-2;

    //loops through each cell in current row
    var item = [];
    item["destination"] = oCells.item(0).innerHTML;
    item["criteria"] = oCells.item(1).innerHTML;
    item["material"] = oCells.item(2).innerHTML;

    DataList.push(item)

    request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("POST", "DOM_SAVE.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    request.send(DataList);

  }
  console.log(DataList);
}
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php

$DataList = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo '$DataList';

  ?>
```

Comment: Please post your php code in your question.

Comment: What does `DOM_SAVE.php` look like?

Comment: You can't send `DataList` directly, you need to serialize it with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Code updated pls see

Comment: Will I serialize the whole DataList array? @Barmar

Comment: If that's what you want to send to PHP, yes.

Comment: If so, how will my php code be able to receive the data? @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize the `DataList` array:

```
request.send(JSON.stringify(DataList));
```

And you shouldn't be sending the request inside the `for` loop. Construct the entire `DataList` in the loop, then send the AJAX request at the end.

And if you want to send an array of objects with named properties, you shouldn't use an array as the elements. Change

```
var item = [];
```

to

```
var item = {};
```

```js
function SaveData() {

  var DataList = [];
  var table = document.getElementById("bod");
  var rowLength = table.rows.length;

  //loops through rows    
  for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {

    //gets cells of current row  
    var oCells = table.rows.item(i).cells;

    //gets amount of cells of current row
    //var cellLength = oCells.length-2;

    //loops through each cell in current row
    var item = {};
    item["destination"] = oCells.item(0).innerHTML;
    item["criteria"] = oCells.item(1).innerHTML;
    item["material"] = oCells.item(2).innerHTML;

    DataList.push(item)


  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request.open("POST", "DOM_SAVE.php", true)
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
  request.send(JSON.stringify(DataList));

  console.log(DataList);
}
```

In PHP, you'll want to decode it:

```
$DataList = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
var_dump($DataList);
```

Comment: Should I use a submit button like this?
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "SaveData()"> @Barmar

Comment: Use `type="button"`, so it won't perform a normal form submission.

Comment: my var_dump value is null @Barmar

Comment: Yuo shouldn't send the AJAX request in the loop, do it after the loop.

Comment: Should I put the ajax request into another function to be called? Im sorry Im so lost, Im new to this things @Barmar

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting it in `SaveData`. Just put it at the end of the loop, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: My php is in another file, should I include it on my html/javascript file or should I combine my php and html/javascript in one file? Because it still shows null value @Barmar

Comment: You can organize things however you like. But if you have them in the same file, you need to add checks that detect whether the file was loaded by the browser or from an AJAX request. It's easier to have them in separate files.

Comment: What do you see from `console.log(DataList)` in the browser?

Comment: The selected values in array. But in var_dump[DataList] is shows null @Barmar

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening. Turn on PHP error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. What does `echo json_last_error();` show in PHP?

Comment: Can we talk in a private chat so I can show the whole code to you? @Barmar

Comment: You don't have enough rep to chat.

Comment: I see. I'll borrow an account, been debugging this for weeks. Glad you could help @Barmar

Comment: My full code accidentally block left out `JSON.stringify()`, did you remember to keep that? I just fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Yes I've added JSON.stringify(), can we have chat using my other account 1vehvehveh7? I have atleast 26 rep there

Comment: I'm embarassed to say that I don't actually know how to start a chat, I only do them when SO automatically offers to move comments to chat when they've gone on too long.

Comment: I also dont knoow how to. Im so noob at these @Barmar

Comment: I created a chatroom and sent an invite to your other account